# Deleting from Laravel 4 cache using pattern for key?

Tags: php, caching, laravel, laravel-4

For my package we make use of the Laravel cache,

Every cache key we create is prefixed, so we get `mypackage-config`, `mypackage-md5ofafilename` At times I need to flush all cache files that my package has created, the issue? I only know the pattern of the cache keys, I don't know the entire key!

So, I need a way to go `Cache::forget('mypackage-*')` or similar, is this possible?

If it was just for my system I know I am using the file cache, so I could manually unlink the files, but because it is a generic package I don't know what cache method the end user is using, I just know the interface (aka the Laravel cache interface).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easy - use `Cache::getMemory()`

```
foreach (Cache::getMemory() as $cacheKey => $cacheValue)
{
    if (strpos($cacheKey, 'mypackage') !== false)
    {
        Cache::forget($cacheKey);
    }
}
```

p.s. dont ever unlink 'cache' files manually. Laravel cache keeps a record of all cache records in an array, so it will be expecting the file to be there, even if you 'unlink' it.

Comment: Just to note, with file cache and Redis, using Laravel 4, this does not work. it says getMemory() method is not found.

Comment: getMemory() is available for memcache only

Comment: this throws a `"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\\Cache\\MemcachedStore' does not have a method 'getMemory'","file":"\/Users\/ericcumbee\/Desktop\/phpprojects\/sblitz\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Cache\/Repository.php","line":277}` error for me in Laravel 4.2 using memcached

Comment: A bit late, but... getMemory() isn't supported any more.

Answer (score 17):

Another solution: as long as you **are not** using file or database cache you can make use of [Cache Tags](http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/cache#cache-tags).

Just tag every cache entry with your package name:

```
Cache::tags('myPackage')->put('config', $config, $minutes);
Cache::tags('myPackage')->put('md5ofafilename', $md5, $minutes);
```

(You can also use the `tags` method with `remember`, `forever`, and `rememberForever`)

When it's time to flush the cache of your package's entries just do

```
Cache::tags('myPackage')->flush();
```

**Note:**
When you need to access the cache entries you still need to reference the tags. E.g.

```
$myConfig = Cache::tags('myPackage')->get('config');
```

That way, another cache entry with key `config` having a different tag (e.g. `hisPackage`) will not conflict with yours.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the same solution as in the accepted answer, but rewritten specifically for Redis.

Using KEYS

```
$redis = Cache::getRedis();
$keys = $redis->keys("*");

foreach ($keys as $key) {
  if (strpos($key, 'mypackage') !== false)
  {
    $redis->del($key);
  }
}
```

Using SCAN (Redis >= 2.8.0)

```
$redis = Cache::getRedis();
$cursor = 0;

while($data = $redis->scan($cursor))
{
  $cursor = $data[0];

  foreach($data[1] as $key)
  {
    if (strpos($key, 'mypackage') !== false)
      {
        $redis->del($key);
      }
    }
  }

  if ($cursor == 0) break;
}
```

Comment: the use of `KEYS` is highly discouraged as it is an O(N) command (i.e. you could trigger a DoS by running it as well as exhausting your server's RAM in preparing the reply's buffer). As of v2.8 the recommended approach is to use the `SCAN` command.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Redis specific example to clear all keys based on a given prefix. This is based on Kazik's answer, with some restructuring and added safety.

Note that RedisStore is under the namespace `Illuminate\Cache\RedisStore`

```
$cacheDriver = Cache::driver();
if ($cacheDriver instanceof(RedisStore)) {
    $cursor = 0;
    do {
        $data = $cacheDriver->scan($cursor);
        $cursor = $data[0];
        $cacheEntries = $data[1];

        foreach ($cacheEntries as $key) {
            // This clears based on prefix. Change according to your use case.
            if (starts_with($key, Cache::getPrefix())) {
                $redis->del($key);
            }
        }

    } while ($cursor != 0);
}
```